# JavaScript issues regarding events for dynamically created HTML

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic, onclick, dom-events

I have some issues with targeting dynamically created elements with JavaScript.

## Issue 1

Shortened JavaScript code:

```
var lightbox = document.createElement('div'),
    nav = document.createElement("nav"),
    imga = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery a");
for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
    imga[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.body.insertBefore(lightbox, document.body.firstChild);
        lightbox.appendChild(nav);
    });
}
```

1: Now I want to make an event on my `<nav>`. How do I get the event to target `#lightbox nav a` instead of just `#lightbox nav`?

```
nav.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // works, but I want to target only the <a> links inside
});
```

I've tried many things, like this:

```
var selector = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
for (i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
    selector[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        // doesn't work because the <nav> is inserted dynamically
    });
}
```

And this:

```
var selector = nav.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < selector.length; i++) {
    selector[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        // doesn't work because the <nav> is inserted dynamically
    });
}
```

## Issue 2

Shortened JavaScript code:

```
var img,
    imga = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery a");
for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
    imga[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
                img = document.createElement("img");
                lightbox.appendChild(img);
            }
    });
}
```

2: How do I add an event to the dynamically created `#lightbox img`? The `img = document.createElement("img")` has to be inside of the function to append multiple images, and for that reason I can't do like this (like currently on `<nav>`):

```
img.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // doesn't work because img = document.createElement("img")
    // has to be inside another function
});
```

Can somebody please assist me on this? I'm not very experienced in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the solution wasn't too hard. With @adeneo getting me to think about nesting event handlers, it turned out to work just fine - and I was able to use all my selectors without modifications:

```
var lightbox = document.createElement('div'),
    nav = document.createElement("nav"),
    imga = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery a"),
    gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery"),
    img;
for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
    imga[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        lightbox.appendChild(nav);
        document.body.insertBefore(lightbox, document.body.firstChild);
        for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
            img = document.createElement("img");
            lightbox.appendChild(img);
        }
        lightbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // works fine
        });
        var nava = document.querySelectorAll("#lightbox nav a");
        for (i = 0; i < nava.length; i++) {
            nava[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                // works fine
            });
        }
        var limg = document.querySelectorAll("#lightbox img");
        for (i = 0; i < limg.length; i++) {
            limg[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                // works fine
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Next Up... [Promises](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/callbacks-promises-signals-and-events/)

Comment: @EddieB I haven't read on what promises actually are, could they be implemented in my case?

Answer (score 3):

## Issue 2

The easy solution is to add the event handler to all the elements inside the loop

```
var img,
    imga = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery a");

for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
    imga[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
            img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src", imga[i].getAttribute("href"));
            lightbox.appendChild(img);

            img.addEventListener('click', fn, false);
        }
    });
}
```

the somewhat harder solution is to use delegated event handlers

```
var img,
    imga = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery a");

lightbox.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if ( e.target.nodeType.toLowerCase() === 'img' ) {
         // do stuff
    }
}, false);

for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
    imga[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        for (i = 0; i < imga.length; i++) {
            img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src", imga[i].getAttribute("href"));
            lightbox.appendChild(img);
        }
    });
}
```

## Issue 1

can be solved like above, with a delegated event handler

```
nav.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if ( e.target.nodeType.toLowerCase() === 'a' ) {

         // an achor was clicked, do stuff

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your "delegated event handlers" doesn't look very elegant, there aren't any better solutions? And, if I put things like `e.stopPropagation()` and `this` inside of these if-statements, what will they target? The `this` statement, among others, are relying on the function selector, right?

Comment: If you want more elegant, you should look closer at how jQuery does it. jQuery binds the `event.target` as `this` in the event handlers, so that `this` actually becomes the dynamic element etc. So it is possible to create convience functions that look better than just checking the `nodeType`. However, in principle this is exactly what jQuery and other libraries do, they attach the event handler to a parent element, relying on bubbling, and then check if any element up the DOM tree from the event.target matches a certain string selector etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't write an entire selector engine and event handling library as an answer, I can only show you how delegated event handler work in principle, and you have to spend all the hours making something that fits your needs.

Comment: I'm sure it does. I just want as minimal code as possible. However, in your first solution, I got inspired to nest all my event handlers inside the first one, something that turned out to work perfectly in my case (see my posted answer). Thanks for your help!